# Compare List<String[]> With Multiple Conditions

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have two `List<String[]>`'s (string array lists), and I'd like to match the contents with each other with some condition so final result will return true of false.

```
List<string> TestA= {"A001","A002","A003","B001","B001","C003","D000","E001"};

List<string> TestB= {"A001","A002","A003","B999","C003"};
```

i would like to write a function for below condition.

1. if All the items of TestA match with TestB (In TestA same item can be multiple times [ex. B001]) ==> return true
2. if TestB conatins any item having digit 999 [Ex B999] then no need to loop for items start with B in testA (this set bool true) and loop of TestA start from C003 [in this case i think we need to remove all Items of B from ListA if ListB conats B999].
   Continue..
   so loop run for TestA item C003. this matched with item in TestB again set true
   Now for D000 not match item in ListB now finally bool set to false and break.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. what have you tried?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icomparer.aspx

Comment: I tried many ways ==> nested loops but i want some good suggestion.

Comment: Right now i don't have code and link as Royi shared its only doing comparision between lists.but i want to skip all particular items  from ListA [ex. like B items] loop if in ListB Item Contains B999...kindda example

Comment: I'm confused, do you have a list of string arrays (as your opening statement indicates) or do you have a list of strings (which the code sample seems to indicate)?

Comment: Well if you tried nested loops - show us that? Its hard to 'help' without knowing what you've got plus we can help you learn what you did wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Here's all you need using LINQ:

```
// Condition 2:
// Get the characters of in list B that contains the "999" string. 
var badOnes = ListB.Where(s=>s.Contains("999").Select(s=>s[0])

// If there is any forbidden characters remove them from List A
if (badOnes.Length > 0)
{
    ListA.RemoveAll(x => x[0] == badOnes.Exists(c => c == x));
}

// Condition 1:
if (ListA.Distinct().Intersect(ListB).Length == ListA.Distinct().Length)
{
    return true;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: If my comment was helpful, please consider marking it as answer.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understood, but check this:

```
var filter = 
    from b in TestB
    where b.Contains("999")
    select b.Replace("999", "");

var cleaned = 
    from a in TestA
    where !filter.Any(f => a.StartsWith(f))
    select a;

var check = cleaned.Distinct()
                   .Except(TestB).Any();
```

**EDIT**

From your further specification I understand your prefixes might have more than one letter, so I edited my answer.